# Arduino IDE error-unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""f900ff'

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to prepare an IR remote control for D2H using Arduino. I have the original codes for each key on the remote.

The code I am working on is a below:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  float khz = 0.07412;
  unsigned char irSignal[]={6F900FF,6F9807F};//codes for key 0, key 1
  irsend.sendRaw(irSignal[0], 20, khz);
  delay(5000); 
}
```

The link below shows the error message. What does this error mean?How it can be removed?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: And `6F900FF` is a 27-bit number. A `char` can only store 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a good hard look at what sendRaw expects as arguments.

This is questionable, as you are trying to store a floating point value, into an integer.

```
int khz = 0.07412
```

I would guess that you should be using a float.

```
float khz = 0.07412;
```

The irSignal is questionable as well, as the initializers that you have look like they are intended to be hex.  They are not specified as hex.   I suspect you are looking for

```
unsigned char irSignal[] = {0x6f,0x90,0x0f,0xf0,0x6f,0x98,0x07,0x0f};
```

Google that function call, and see if you can find a page that describes what data types must be passed to the function call.